# Solve for real numbers $x$ and $y$, simultaneously the equations given by $xy^2 = 15x^2 + 17xy + 15y^2$ and $x^2y = 20x^2 + 3y^2$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, problem-solving

> Solve for real numbers $x$ and $y$, simultaneously the equations given by
> $$
> \left\{
> \begin{array}{l}
> xy^2 &= 15x^2 + 17xy + 15y^2 \\
> x^2y &= 20x^2 + 3y^2
> \end{array}
> \right.
> $$

by taking $y = xt$, I get $x=0$ and $y=0$. Is there some other way or some other solution? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Subbing $y = x t$ is a good idea. Since you've already found $x = y = 0$, let's assume $x \ne 0$. Doing the substitution and simplifying gives
$$
xt^2 = 15 t^2 + 17 t + 15 \\
x t = 20 + 3t^2.
$$
Multiply the bottom equation by $t$ and subtract to get
$$
0 = t(3t^2 + 20) - (15t^2 + 17 t + 15)= 3t^3 -15 t^2 + 3t - 15 = 3(t-5)(t^2+1)
$$
which has the real solution $t = 5$. From this, we find the solution $(x, y) = (19, 95)$.

Answer (score 1):

We can linearize this system by introducing variables for the monomials. Then there are exactly four solutions
$$
(x,y)= (0,0),(19,95),(-17i,17),(17i,17).
$$